# SymmetricDS Two Way Sync via Column Match Router

Tags: symmetricds

I have 3 nodes, 1 is host (called 'A') and 2 are guest (called 'B' and 'C') that refer to the host.

One day, 'A' send data to 'B' via Column Match Router, unfortunately 'A' is wrong.
'A' should send data to 'C', but the data have been recorded in 'B' and also in 'C' (after resent to 'C').

How to delete data in 'B'? Or the other question is how to make two way sync via column match router?
At the end, I want to sync host and targeted guest, even if I fix the row so there is no "not-related-column" in wrong node.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Subselect Router](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_subselect_router):

> A 'subselect' router can be used in these cases. A 'subselect' is
>   configured with a router expression that is a SQL select statement
>   which returns a result set of the node ids that need routed to. Column
>   tokens can be used in the SQL expression and will be replaced with row
>   column data.

Use:

```
symadmin send-sql --node B mytable "delete from mytable where id = 257"
```

to delete mistakenly sent data on the node B.

Comment: Is there any 'automatic' command or configuration that allow me to only edit the data from host and the guest is following?

Comment: Yes, triggers are defined per group. So, if your host A belongs to the group 'central' and guests are belonging to the group 'remote' and triggers are only defined for nodes belonging to 'central' then no changes will be synced from guests to the host.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your reply. After read the Subselect Router doc, I think it has same purpose with Column Match Router. I mean automatic is when you make a false routing, you just edit the data routing (let say change row from B to C) and not using any code, because it has been configured before. Thank you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What configuration that can resolve false routing by just edit the data? This resolve include deleting and rerouting data.

Comment: What does it mean to 'resolve false routing'? Delete the data at the target node? Change the routing so next changes get synced to the right target nodes?

Comment: Yes, delete data from false target node, and routing again to the right target node.

Comment: To delete use the command `symadmin send-sql --node B mytable "delete from mytable where id = 257"`. The sole act of updating a row in the host table having the column used for routing will trigger an extraction and the row will be synced to the new target.

Comment: Thank you, it works. So the conclusions are: there is no resync configuration for the false routing case, so you must delete it manually from sql.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110830/discussion-between-yosua-lijanto-binar-and-boris-pavlovic).